# Adding react to html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I managed to understand how to add React to HTML, but faced a question. In tutorials I saw React is adding directly to HTML with 3 react scripts in head. In other I saw react is adding to JS file with `import React from 'react'` etc. When I connect js file in HTML, I write `<script src="script.js" type="text/babel"></script>` But if I didn't add those 3 scripts in head, but have import in js, nothing works.
So, question is, how to add JS file with React with imports in js file, if it's possible.

Doesn't work with started  `>npx serve`

Example of code that doesn't work:
**rh.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="rh.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**rh.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const element = (
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
)

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: How is your setup? Are you actually using babel? Note that you have a .js file, but .jsx syntax which needs to be transpiled to js

Comment: @Celsiuss to be honest, don't really understand

Comment: React is usually written in JSX, which is an extension of JS, and allows for using tags inside JS code (like you do with e.g. `<table>`). Browsers however only understand JS, so something (e.g. Babel) needs to convert JSX to JS. If you just want to try React, you can use Babel with the `type="text/babel"` and the script tags like you did, but not for production. Your question is how to replace that approach with a production-ready approach. For beginners, I would advise using a starter kit that gets you bootstrapped quickly: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: I know what is JSX already, and saw this tutorial how to start React App. It created lot of different files, I saw them all. But I ask if it is possible to do all that stuff, without this App.js from React create. Just I simply create html and js files, import React in js, connect it to HTML and it works? Need to build this App.js with ```export default App```

Comment: Also what errors do you get? Saying "nothing works" rarely helps

Comment: @Celsiuss that's the thing. No errors, it just doesn't show me anything. Console doesn't return any issues.

Comment: Yeah the script type specified is not supported by the browser, and thus wont load at all. You should stick to something like CRA. If you really want to make a barebones dev application, read this section from the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx

Comment: @Celsiuss actually, I've checked html and js files with starting React app like described on site, and I can't get it. Js file has react imports and html file doesn't have react scripts in head or body, and everything works somehow. The question, why it doesn't work in my case

Comment: You still need to import the react javascript code in html. Check this example taken from the page I linked: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/main/static/html/single-file-example.html

Comment: @Celsiuss I've found solution for myself, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. Somebody told me to use `npx serve` to start localhost, but if I wanted my React to work without `<script>` in html file, I need to write `npm start` in console